# Powershell with mediainfo command for each file in directory

Tags: powershell, scripting, mediainfo

I'm trying to execute the command: `.\mediainfo.exe --Output=XML "$path\file\*.*" > .\file\$output.xml` for multiple media files in a folder. Here's what I have currently:

```
$path = get-item F:\Desktop\work\
cd $path
$output = (Get-ChildItem '.\file\*.*').Basename
.\mediainfo.exe --Output=XML "$path\file\*.*" > .\file\$output.xml
```

My issue is that MediaInfo.exe will create on XML output file containing all information from all media in the folder F:\Desktop\work\file.

I tried the following:

```
$path = get-item F:\Desktop\work\
$dir = get-item $path\file | ? {$_.PSIsContainer}
cd $path
$output = (Get-Item '.\file\*.*').Basename
ForEach ($d in $dir){.\mediainfo.exe --Output=XML "$d" > .\file\$output.xml
}
```

But same thing. Name of the output.xml will be concatenated with all media name. For instance if I have two files name
audio1.aif and audio2.aif, the name of my XML will be audio1 audio2.xml

Any idea how to achieve that ? Thanks

Comment: Is there any relationship between the folder names and the expected output file name?

Comment: Not the folder name but the output file must be named as the media file in the file folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I missed something in the question, but for having a sidecar XML file with its file name being the source file name + ".xml", this small script does it:

```
ForEach ($d in get-item "file\*.*"){
  .\mediainfo.exe --Output=XML "$d" > "$d.xml"
}
```

Note: the resulting MediaInfo XML will have the absolute file name (including the path) because the absolute file name is provided to MediaInfo. If you prefer a relative file name (without the current path, and without the directory name containing the files), you need to provide relative file names:

```
$current = (Get-Item .).FullName
cd file
ForEach ($d in Get-Item "*.*"){
  $filename = Split-Path "$d" -Leaf
  ..\mediainfo.exe --Output=XML $filename > "$d.xml"
}
cd $current
```

If you want the XML file without the source file extension (not recommended, issue if you get 2 files with same base name e.g. a.avi and a.srt a sidecar subtitle file for the first file), you need an intermediate variable:

```
$current = (Get-Item .).FullName
cd file
ForEach ($d in Get-Item "*.*"){
  $filename = Split-Path "$d" -Leaf
  #$basename = Split-Path "$d" -LeafBase #Only in newest versions
  $basename = (Get-Item -Path "$d").BaseName
  ..\mediainfo.exe --Output=XML $filename > "$basename.xml"
}
cd $current
```

Comment: Both command works great, thank you! Do you know how can I get the XML name without the media file extension ? I get media.mp4.xml for my XMLs.

Comment: for removing the extension (not recommended, issue if you get 2 files with same base name e.g. a.avi and a.srt a sidecar subtitle file for the first file), replace "-Leaf" by "-LeafBase", see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path).

Comment: Thanks! This won't happenned as I will have only one type of file with unique name. Thanks again. Edit: It didn't work: https://prnt.sc/u78gx0

Comment: I was too quick, looks like the option is available only in newest versions + bad result because I modify the input name and not the output name. I modified the answer with an extra example.

Comment: Hello Jerome, I just realized something with mediainfo output xml. Seems that before <?xml we have some data. I've opened an XML file with an HEX editor and there's indeed something there, but can't be seen with a regular editor. I need to transform this xml using XSLT, unfortunately because of this I get an error during translation: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog. When I copy the data to a new XML, no issue. Any idea on why this is happening ?

Comment: PowerShell adds a [BOM marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and writes in UTF-16LE. This is an arbitrary choice of PowerShell, other interpreter e.g. old Windows command line uses local charset and no BOM. If your XSLT processor does not support BOM and/or UTF-16LE, you can replace ' > "$basename.xml"' by ' "--LogFile=$basename.xml"'., MediaInfo forces the writes in UTF-8 without BOM when directly writing the output to a file.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thanks again Jerome !